# Vue Native NativeBase Header Text Width Issue

Tags: html, css, width, native-base

I'm trying to use Native Base to create a header for my Vue Native mobile application.
However, the `<nb-body>` doesn't seem to take up the right width.

Here is the `<template>` section:

```html
<template>
  <nb-container>
    <nb-header>
      <nb-left>
        <nb-button transparent>
          <nb-icon name="menu" :on-press="toggleDrawer" />
        </nb-button>
      </nb-left>
      <nb-body>
        <nb-title class="header-text">{{headerTitle}}</nb-title>
      </nb-body>
      <nb-right>
        <nb-button transparent>
          <nb-icon name="funnel" />
        </nb-button>
      </nb-right>
    </nb-header>
    <slot />
  </nb-container>
</template>
```

And here is my CSS:

```css
<style>
  .header-text{
    font-family: Graduate-Regular;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

[An example of what this looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c1KQ.png)

My `headerTitle` cuts off into ellipses (...) even when it has more room to use. When I add something like `width: 120%` to my CSS, it fits. But, and correct me if I'm wrong here, I don't think it is good practice to put an arbitrary amount for the width.

Is there any way to let the `nb-body` take up all the space between the `nb-left` and the `nb-right`, or maybe a way to let it take up just as much space as it needs?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex`. In this scenario they add up to 1. The left and right take up 1/5 and 1/5 of the header. The Body with take up 3/5.

```
      <nb-left :style="{flex:.2}>
        <nb-button transparent>
          <nb-icon name="menu" :on-press="toggleDrawer" />
        </nb-button>
      </nb-left>
      <nb-body :style="{flex:.6}>
        <nb-title class="header-text">{{headerTitle}}</nb-title>
      </nb-body>
      <nb-right :style="{flex:.2}>
        <nb-button transparent>
          <nb-icon name="funnel" />
        </nb-button>
      </nb-right>
```

Comment: The logic behind it works but it's not entirely correct for Vue Native. My line looks like this: ```<nb-left :style="{flex:.2}">``` This actually solves my problem, I'll accept this when edits are made so it follows the right syntax.